# google map module in joomla

Tags: google-maps, joomla

I have seen some website has a searching textbox in google map. How to add this textbox in google map on my site (using joomla)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phoca Maps](http://www.phoca.cz/phocamaps) extension should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

or http://tech.reumer.net/Google-Maps/Documentation-of-plugin-Googlemap/Welcome.html - nice and simple plugin